# How to compile only the changed files in Verilator?

Tags: compilation, verilog, register-transfer-level, verilator

I use Verilator to compile and simulate my design. The whole compilation and simulation takes forever. Since I am testing a feature, I only change one module in the design every time. I want know if there is a way to only compile the changed file instead of the entire design every time.

For e.g. if my hierarchy is this

```
      TOP
      / \
     A   B
    / \
  a1  a2
```

I only change a2. So I want Verilator to only compile a2 again instead of the entire design.

Comment: What you are looking for is called incremental Compilation. Verilator supports incremental compilation that allows to recompile only the changed files rather than the entire design.